# CVS Checkout Problem

Tags: cvs

I set up a CVS repository on the server.

Then I used Eclipse to sync the repository with my local computer, using ext (*not extssh*). Now updates/commits from Eclipse work fine. However, when I try to commit or update using Tortoise CVS, I get the following error -

```
cvs [checkout aborted]: end of file from server (consult above messages if any).
```

Could someone tell me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your paths are set correctly. One thing I learned the hard way from Eclipse is that even though I added the .JAR files to Eclipse, when I ran something outside of Eclipse, it failed miserably because the classpath variables were not set correctly. I'm not sure if you are experiencing a similar issue, but it may be something to look into perhaps.

I will dig around a bit and see if I can find anything else in the meantime.

Comment: Ok. Also, someone mentioned that the PATH variable on the server needs to point to cvs; tried that but that didn't help either.